# How to use Array.prototype.flat in flatlist react native?

Tags: javascript

where and how to use this `Array.prototype.flat` in react native using a flatlist?

this works fine

```
<FlatList         
          data={data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return (
              <View >
                  <Text>{item[0].name}</Text>
                <Text>{item[0].book}</Text>
                 <Text>{item[0].number}</Text>
              </View>
                )
          }} />
```

```
 const data =[
   { 
      "number": 12,
      "book": "Red Hood",
      "name": "crystal"
  },
]
```

but this below does not work how to access the data when it is like this below to use in flatlist?

```
 const data =[
  [
    {
        "number": 12,
        "Book": "Red Hood",
        "name": "crystal"
    },
  ]
]
```

Comment: Use `item[0]` instead of `item`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is just one item wrapped in the array, you could just do `item[0].name` `item[0].Book` and `item[0].number`

if you have an array of arrays, you can use `Array.prototype.flat` [[read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)..] to create a single array

> The flat() method creates a new array with all sub-array elements concatenated into it recursively up to the specified depth.

**Update**
In your case

```js
const old_data = [
   { 
      "number": 12,
      "book": "Red Hood",
      "name": "crystal"
  },
] 

const new_data = [
  [
    {
        "number": 12,
        "Book": "Red Hood",
        "name": "crystal"
    },
  ]
];

const converted_data = new_data.flat(); // will be same as old_data

console.log(converted_data);
```

Comment: happy to help! :)

Comment: where and how to use this ```Array.prototype.flat```in the flatlist? @DhananjaiPai

Comment: still don't get it could you please show me and example with the codes above or so? @DhananjaiPai

Comment: please give variable names and update your question. the question has very little information to give actual code answer

Comment: i just did @DhananjaiPai

Comment: Yeah, I have updated the answer, sorry I was also confused with the flat function earlier.